# How to use marshmallow-sqlalchemy with async code?

Tags: sqlalchemy, aiohttp, marshmallow

I'm trying to use marshmallow-sqlalchemy with aiohttp and I have followed their docs with the basic example and I'm getting an error.

I have this schema:

```
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema

from db.customer import Customer

class CustomerSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        include_relationships = True
        load_instance = True
```

And then the following code for the query:

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from db import db_conn
from db.customer import Customer
from queries.schema import CustomerSchema

customer_schema = CustomerSchema()

async def get_all_users():
    async with db_conn.get_async_sa_session() as session:
        statement = select(Customer)
        results = await session.execute(statement)
        _ = (results.scalars().all())
        print(_)
        response = customer_schema.dump(_, many=True)
        print(response)
```

For the first print statement I'm getting

```
[<db.customer.Customer object at 0x10a183340>, <db.customer.Customer object at 0x10a183940>, <db.customer.Customer object at 0x10b0cd9d0>]
```

But then it fails with

```
File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 60, in await_only
    raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s)
```

So how can I use marshmallow-sqlalchemy to serialize the SqlAlchemy reponse?

Another options (packages, etc) or a generic custom solutions are OK too.

For the time being I'm using this:

```
statement = select(Customer)
results = await session.execute(statement)
_ = (results.scalars().all())
response = {}
for result in _:
    value = {k: (v if not isinstance(v, sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState) else '_') for k, v in result.__dict__.items()}
    response[f'customer {value["id"]}'] = value
return response
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 422, in _handle_request
    resp = await self._request_handler(request)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 499, in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py", line 948, in _iter
    resp = await method()
  File "/Users/ruslan/OneDrive/Home/Dev/projects/code/education/other/cft/views/user.py", line 24, in get
    await get_all_users()
  File "/Users/ruslan/OneDrive/Home/Dev/projects/code/education/other/cft/queries/user.py", line 18, in get_all_users
    response = customer_schema.dump(_, many=True)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 547, in dump
    result = self._serialize(processed_obj, many=many)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 509, in _serialize
    return [
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 510, in <listcomp>
    self._serialize(d, many=False)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 515, in _serialize
    value = field_obj.serialize(attr_name, obj, accessor=self.get_attribute)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py", line 310, in serialize
    value = self.get_value(obj, attr, accessor=accessor)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/fields.py", line 27, in get_value
    return super(fields.List, self).get_value(obj, attr, accessor=accessor)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py", line 239, in get_value
    return accessor_func(obj, check_key, default)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 472, in get_attribute
    return get_value(obj, attr, default)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow/utils.py", line 239, in get_value
    return _get_value_for_key(obj, key, default)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/marshmallow/utils.py", line 253, in _get_value_for_key
    return getattr(obj, key, default)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 480, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(state, dict_)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 931, in get
    value = self.callable_(state, passive)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 879, in _load_for_state
    return self._emit_lazyload(
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 1036, in _emit_lazyload
    result = session.execute(
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1689, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1582, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/lambdas.py", line 481, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1451, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1813, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1998, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1770, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 449, in execute
    self._adapt_connection.await_(
  File "/Users/ruslan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cft-RKlbQ9iX/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 60, in await_only
    raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem in this case is that the Marshmallow schema is configured to load related models (`include_relationships=True`).  Since the initial query doesn't load them automatically, the schema triggers a query to fetch them, and this causes the error.

The simplest solution, demonstrated in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html?highlight=asyncio#synopsis-orm), is to eagerly load the related objects with their "parent":

```py
async def get_all_users():
    async with db_conn.get_async_sa_session() as session:

        # Let's assume a Customer has a 1 to many relationship with an Order model
        statement = select(Customer).options(orm.selectinload(Customer.orders))

        results = await session.execute(statement)
        _ = (results.scalars().all())
        print(_)
        response = customer_schema.dump(_, many=True)
        print(response)
```

There is more discussion in the [Preventing Implicit IO when Using AsyncSession](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html?highlight=asyncio#preventing-implicit-io-when-using-asyncsession) section of the docs.